# Exporting Scenes from Unreal Engine to Blender

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender and have used Lightwave 3d as my main animation software. I am debating switching and would like to know if there is a plugin or easy way to export scenes from Unreal Engine into blender?

Most software exports into Unreal Engine but I am interested in the ability to export a scene to blender. Doing it all one piece by one piece is what I have had to do in Lightwave so it would be amazing if you could export an entire scene to blender and have surfaces be somewhat correct. Thanks